# Mongoose Document.isModified(path:string) returns true for unmodified paths

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can i make isModified return true for only modified paths? I am attempting to hash a user's password with a pre save middleware, the hashing function should ideally only be called when the password has changed but instead it is called on every user save to the database because this.isModifed("password") keeps returning true even when the password has not changed. This is also the same case with other paths.

Mongoose version: "^7.2.1"

UserSchema.ts:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IUser, IUserModel, IUserMethods>(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      },
    email: {
      type: String,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, ValidationErrorMessages.required("password")],
      minlength: [6, ValidationErrorMessages.tooShort("password")],
      maxlength: [30, ValidationErrorMessages.tooLong("password")],
    },
    following: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

UserModel.ts:

```
export interface IUser {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  following: Types.ObjectId[];
}
export interface IUserDocument extends IUser, Document {}

export interface IUserMethods {
  follow(
    this: IUserThisContext,
    user: HydratedDocument<IUser, IUserMethods>
  ): IUserMutationResult;
}

export type IUserThisContext = HydratedDocument<IUser> & Document;

export type IUserModel = Model<IUserDocument, object, IUserMethods>;

export type IUserMutationResult = Promise<HydratedDocument<IUser> | null>;

userSchema.pre("save", function (this: IUserThisContext,next:any) {
  console.log(this.isModified("password")); //true
  console.log(this.isModified("username")); //true
  console.log(this.isModified("email")); //true
  if(!this.isModified("password")) return next();
  this.password = bcryt.hashSync(this.password, 10);
//called everytime
  next();
});

userSchema.methods = {
follow(this, user) {
    this.following.push(user._id);
    const saved = await this.save();// triggers pre save middleware
    return saved;
  },
};

const User = mongoose.model<IUserDocument, IUserModel>("User", userSchema);
export default User;
```

Index.ts

```
    const user = new User(UserData.user1);
    await user.save(); //triggers pre save middleware
    const user2 = new User(UserData.user2);
    await user2.save(); //triggers pre save middleware
    console.log(await user.follow(user2));
// ValidationError: User validation failed: password: password is too long
```

UserData.ts

```
class UserData {
    public static readonly user1 = {
        username: "hilda",
        email: "hilda@gmail.com",
        password: "demonlover"
    };

    public static readonly user2 = {
        username: "ben10",
        email: "maxten@gmail.com",
        password: "gwenten"
    };
}
```

I get a validation error of "password is too long" because it attempts to call bcrypt.hashSync() again on the already hashed password when a user follows another user because this.isModified("password") returns true even when the password has not changed. this.isNew also behaves the same way.